# How to decrypt LUKS-encrypted device on per user basis upon login?

Tags: systemd, login, luks, d-bus, cryptsetup

I've created the following `luks@.service` service for `systemd`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Cryptography Setup for '%I'
After=cryptsetup-pre.target
After=dev-mapper-%i.device
Before=cryptsetup.target
Before=umount.target
BindsTo=dev-mapper-%i.device
BindsTo=dev-mapper-%i.luks.device
Conflicts=umount.target
DefaultDependencies=no
IgnoreOnIsolate=true
RequiresMountsFor=/home

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup attach '%I.luks' '/dev/mapper/%I' '%h/%I/secret.key' 'luks,header=%h/%I/header'
ExecStop=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup detach '%I.luks'
KillMode=none
RemainAfterExit=yes
TimeoutSec=0
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The idea is to decrypt certain LUKS-encrypted `xxx` device as `xxx.luks` only for a given user, who enables the service with, for example:

```
systemctl --user enable luks@xxx
```

Unfortunately, even testing it with

```
systemctl --user start luks@xxx
```

fails as it always returns with exit code `1` without stating the actual reason.  To me it was clear that the problem is likely in permissions.  That is I know for sure that in order to manually trigger `cryptsetup luksOpen ...`, one has to elevate the shell, e.g. with `sudo`.  Indeed, if I issue

```
sudo systemctl start luks@xxx
```

it works like a charm and similarly

```
sudo systemctl enable luks@xxx
```

would work for boot phase.

> **NOTE:**
>   For such system-wide installation, it is of course needed to modify the service by replacing `%h` with the actual home directory of a giver user, which is ugly and does not serve the final purpose anyway.

Now, I'm aware of `pam_mount` which is capable of doing similar mounting (which I cannot use because it does not support detached LUKS headers and because it actually mounts devices, something what I don't want) on per user basis and, in fact, `pam_systemd` launches `systemctl --user`, so there definitely should be a way to obtain privileges during boot on per user basis to perform the device decryption.

By the way, failure symptoms of

```
systemctl --user enable luks@xxx
```

are even worse than those of testing it with

```
systemctl --user start luks@xxx
```

(which only returns exit code `1`).  That is I cannot even log in with the given user as it complains about

```
Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory
```

because `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` and `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` are not set anymore, while they should have been by the `systemd-logind.service` service.  Clearly, `luks@xxx` somehow breaks the whole initialization process but due to insufficient information in journal, I cannot identify exactly why.  Thus, my current suspicion about lack of permissions still remains.

Looking forward to educated proposals.  Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/996155/how-do-i-automatically-decrypt-an-encrypted-filesystem-on-the-next-reboot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative solution would be to edit the `sudoers` file to add permissions for the user in question to run `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup` with root permissions with NOPASSWD option enabled.

You would then edit your (user-specific) service file above to read:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup attach '%I.luks' '/dev/mapper/%I' '%h/%I/secret.key' 'luks,header=%h/%I/header'
ExecStop=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup detach '%I.luks'
```

I'm not sure whether you would also have to enable [!requiretty](https://serverfault.com/questions/246135/is-it-possible-to-use-sudo-with-requiretty-for-a-specific-command) for this to work

#### Update:

To increase security around this, especially for a multiple-user system, I'd highly recommend creating a couple of scripts to perform the 'attach' and 'detach' steps on behalf of the user rather than giving sudo access to `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup` directly, as otherwise any user that is given access to run this command can potentially interfere with other encrypted volumes.

Comment: I've chosen this solution as the configuration can be user-independent (e.g. by using the `%wheel` group instead) and is also the least impacting one.  By the way, I didn't need `!requiretty` for it to work.  Though, I'm still perplexed about why lack of permissions ruined the whole initialization process (my understanding was that `systemd` units are isolated from each other and cannot potentially cause such damage).  In any case, thanks for you rich inputs.

Comment: I'm not sure what is confusing you, but I'll attempt to help: User systemd managers are run at the permission level of the user and have access to resources that the user does. Only the user (and root) has access to services managed as such. The system systemd manager is run as root and has access to all resources. Only root, and users given specific permissions (through something like sudo or polkit) have access to the system manager's services. There is no default 'isolation' between services, though there are options that can help (PrivateTmp=, User= or ProtectControlGroups= to name a few)

Comment: I meant, why should `Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory` be the result of not having permissions to decrypt a device.  Clearly, those two points have nothing to do with each other in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating and enabling a `Type=oneshot` `RemainAfterExit=yes` service for the user that creates a file with it's `ExecStart` directive, and removes it with it's `ExecStop` directive e.g.

```
ExecStart="/usr/bin/touch %h/.decrypt"
ExecStop="/usr/bin/rm %h/.decrypt"
```

You can then create and enable a `luks@xxx.path` unit file for the system user with an absolute path:

```
PathExists="/home/user/.decrypt"
```

This would check for the path created by the user service above, activating the `luks@xxx.service` unit when it is created, and deactivating it when it is removed, thus establishing an indirect dependency of the system service on the user service.

Note that for this to operate securely, the directory in which the file is created should be writable by the user only, of course.

Comment: This would still require enabling `luks@xxx` system-wide as `root`.  Thanks but this is more of a workaround, not a final solution.

Comment: You don't need to enable `luks@xxx.service`, just the relevant path unit, but I do concede that it is more 'workaround' than 'elegant'. What about using PolicyKit as in the first answer here - https://serverfault.com/a/841150/193286

Comment: Looks interesting.  I'll give it a try.  Though, does that mean that the service will be still enabled system-wide?

Comment: I believe so - I'm not sure how you'd not execute it 'system wide'. For a user instance of a systemd manager to execute something requiring elevated permissions would require itself to be running with elevated permissions (which would be insecure) or perhaps something involving control groups giving the user systemd instance the permissions to manage decryption of the filesystem (which would still be insecure, just more secure than full root permissions).

Comment: Is there a way to rather say "I want this user to be able to decrypt this device without explicitly specifying privileges."?

Comment: Specifying acl permissions on a device node probably is both trickier to set up (especially if this is a removable device) and weaker, security-wise than enabling sudo for specific commands, or signalling to the master systemd instance that it should enable/disable decryption. You may find [this](https://kdecherf.com/blog/2012/11/06/mount-a-luks-partition-with-a-password-protected-gpg-encrypted-key-using-systemd/) useful, though you may not need the GPG elements, and still involves editing `sudoers` as in my other answer.